# Swagger ApiImplicitParams annotation for many methods

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, aspect

I'm trying to document my API with swagger. Authentication is handled with a filter and a header param. So I wanted to use @ApiImplicitParams to explain this but it is not possible to put the annotation on types so I need to put it on all methods... quite annoying! I searched on internet but could not found a good solution.

Did anyone get the same problem (i guess, since i'm not doing extraordinary things) and how did you achieve it ? Any solution with aspect maybe ?

Environment : jee6 / jax-rs 2 / resteasy 3

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the param at the class level:

```
public class PetResource {
  static PetData petData = new PetData();

  @ApiParam(value = "the authorization")
  @HeaderParam("my_auth")
  private String myAuth;
```

This will add parameter to all methods in the class.

Comment: That's finally what i did but i'd prefer a solution with aspects (i have another annotation @Secured and both will always be together)...

Comment: Please add an issue to `swagger-core` so `@ApiImplicitParam` variables can be annotated at the class level.  That should make this work.